How does similarity affect the likelihood of an outcome?
This question sounds vague and I don’t know how to make it specific without an example.
Let’s take the fine tuning argument. This says that if the constants in physical laws  (values without dimensions) were even a tiny bit different, life would not materialize. Thus, some say that the probability of this by chance is infinitesimally low.
Now, this seems to come from merely imagining a universe with the same laws but different constants. In some sense, none of these imagined scenarios are proven to even be possible, but it seems like a natural way to imagine these things. Given that there are an infinite number of ways one can imagine the same laws but with different constants, it seems prime facie improbable for the same narrow range of constants that allow for life to have materialized.
What is one way to escape this improbability? Well, theists propose God, or a designer. This designer supposedly “solves” this improbability.
But the whole problem with the original “designer-less” scenario is that if the constants just happened to be formed in such a way as to result in life, it gives us no explanation as to why the universe would have those constants rather than another.
But even if a designer exists, we still have no ultimate explanation for why those constants were chosen rather than another, since we would also have no explanation for that designer and his choices.
Thus, assuming that there is no independent evidence for god, the fine tuning argument by itself doesn’t really seem to “solve” the improbability. It would only seem to do this if we already had prior evidence that god exists, but that is the very question that needs to be answered.
But why then does it instinctually seem more satisfying to think “god created these constants” rather than “the constants just happen to be this way”? After all, “god created these constants” would be a form of explanation that “happened to be this way” too.
After thinking about it, it seems as if I organize reality into many possible states. For example, a lot of those states are states of reality where there is no designer, with each state corresponding to a different series or constants. Each of these states are similar to each other with the only difference being the values of those constants.
But when it comes to imagining realities with a designer, the state of reality in which there is a designer + life forming constants seems to belong in its own sphere. In a way, this state seems much different from the “designer-less” states. Thus, if this state were true, the question “why these constants rather than another?” would be less natural of a question to ask than in the case of those constants being formed by chance.
So this brings me to my question: how important is similarity between states when it comes to assigning how likely each state is?

I think what you are asking is related to the reference class problem. What you consider to be relevantly similar determines which reference class you assess its probability against. But when it comes to gods, possible universes, and possible values for the fundamental constants, there is no plausible reference class to refer to, so the problem is imponderable.

You first ask:

But why then does it instinctually seem more satisfying to think “god created these constants” rather than “the constants just happen to be this way”?

This is a psychological question, rather than a philisophical question. First, it doesn't "instinctually seem more satisfying" to think that way for many people. But you are right that many people do have a tendancy to search for a cause rather than to accept happenstance as an explanation. This is well researched in relation to conspiracy theories. There is comfort for many people in identifying some source of order or causation behind a phenomenon.
Then, you also ask:

how important is similarity between states when it comes to assigning how likely each state is?

This depends on what your underlying model is regarding how those states are generated. If your underlying model posits that states that are "similar" or "close" in some sense will have similar probabilities of having occurred, then similarity is tremendously important in assigning likelihoods. However your underlying model might posit that there is no meaningful measure of "similarity" between states (e.g. state A being just marginally different from state B implies nothing about their likelihoods also being similar).
Example 1: in baseball, the likelihood that a ball is batted to a particular coordinate in the outfield is highly correlated with the likelihood that a ball is batted to a nearby coordinate in the outfield.
Example 2: in Scrabble, the likelihood of pulling a Q from the pile is not at all correlated with the likelihood of drawing an O from the pile, even though they appear very similar.
